# Ctrl+Shift to Run as Administrator No Longer Works

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, administrator, runas

Holding Ctrl+Shift while clicking on a shortcut (or in the Start Menu’s search box) no longer works to run as administrator. Specifically, nothing happens; no UAC prompt and the program does not run at all.

I can still run things as administrator by using the *run as admin* context-menu item on the EXE, but not on shortcuts to it. I can also run as admin if the *run as admin* property of a shortcut is checked and the shortcut is opened normally. Also, EXEs that have the admin flag (those with the shield icon overlay) work either directly or through the shortcut. It is non-admin programs that cannot be manually run as admin.

The only notable change since this behavior that I can think of is that I disabled the Win-key hotkeys (`NoWinKeys=1`), but that *should* not be related.

Does anyone know what could be causing this? I thought that maybe something in the shortcut handler (`HKCR\lnkfile`) was corrupted, but it *looks* okay.

Comment: Have you tried changing NoWinKeys back to see if that 'fixes' it?

Comment: No. I had considered it, but that would require a reboot, and then another once I confirm that it has nothing to do with it (at least it had dang well better not!) `:-)` I’ll try it tonight before I shutdown.

Comment: Nope. Not surprisingly, it did not fix it. (I’m kind of conflicted about the results.)

Comment: I'm having this issue as well, except that my executables are being opened in a file viewing program, rather than being executed with elevated permissions.

Comment: I'm having this same issue on a new Windows 10 PC, except that the program just DOES run -- except with no UAC prompt and no elevated permissions.

Comment: Just posted a new question for the issue mentioned in my comment above: https://superuser.com/questions/1189406/ctrlshiftenter-to-run-as-admin-works-on-desktop-apps-but-not-run-commands

Comment: The same thing happened to me a few days ago on all my Windows 10 installations. Any attempt to fix the issue was unsuccessful. I am really puzzled. I wish someone knew what is going on :)

Answer (score 4):

> I have had UAC turned off for quite a while now

I suspected that UAC was off while reading the question.

A lot of people misunderstand what the "Run As Administrator" option does.  That has nothing to do with using an account named Administrator or an account that is part of a group named Administrators.  It has everything to do with running a program in a way where UAC will recognize that the program has elevated privileges.  The "Run As Administrator" option does not affect what user account is being used to run the program.

(I wish the option was called "Run Elevated".  As is, the phrasing of that option has confused a lot of people.)

Call it a confusingly-named option if you like, but if you Shift+"Right-click" an icon, you may see the "Run As Administrator" option *only if UAC is enabled*.  Otherwise, that item simply won't exist.  This might have changed a bit with newer operating systems, but this is how this worked in Windows 7 (and Windows Vista).

Therefore, I'm not at all surprised that this keyboard shortcut doesn't work.  I haven't regularly used this shortcut, but it sounds like this shortcut simply performs the functionality of a feature that just doesn't even exist unless UAC is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I have the impression that CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER only works when using the Instant Search feature in the Windows Start menu. Open the Services applet and check if Windows Search Service is enabled. If disabled, see if enabling it changes anything (let it have a few moments to do its indexing).

A question : What happens if you [turn off UAC](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-disable-and-turn-off-uac-in-windows-7/) temporarily ?

Comment: I have had UAC turned off for quite a while now, but I’m fairly sure that it used to work on regular shortcuts as well. Either way, I don’t use the normal Start menu anymore, I use the Classic Shell instead, and Ctrl+Shift+clicking on shortcuts in there *do* prompt for access when UAC is on. Perhaps if I have the time and space, I’ll install 7 in a VM and check with a fresh install.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+click is a standard feature of Windows 7.

Comment: *> Ctrl+Shift+click is a standard feature of Windows 7.* Yes, hence the question.

Comment: Does it work if you login as another user ? Have you done any keyboard mapping ? Or used AutoHotKey ? Or installed any kind of mouse software ?

Comment: Like I said, if I get the time and space, I’ll try a fresh install in a VM. Either way, it is *not* just a feature for Instant Search. Google for `Ctrl+Shift admin` and you’ll find that none of the references mention it working only in the Start menu, and in fact, most specifically say *any shortcut or program*. [For example](http://lifehacker.com/5592973/use-ctrl%252Bshift%252Bclick-to-open-programs-as-administrator-in-windows-7).

Comment: Yes, I know that, and you said that it used to work. But without answers to my question I have no direction.