# Ctrl + Shift + Enter no longer starts programs as admin

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, administrator, windows-11

For a few days we have the problem that the key combination to run programs as admin (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) does not work on all PCs.

The problem exists under Windows 10 as well as Windows 11, but not on all computers. When trying to launch a program with this key combination,  nothing happens.

This problem seems to have appeared suddenly, last week it still worked, now it doesn't, so I strongly assume an update is causing this error.

Has anyone experienced similar problems?

Comment: Not working here either Win 10 / Win 11.  I tried from within a terminal window and Start, program. Nothing.

Comment: afaik that only works using WIN + R, not on start menu options itself. Or rather, that's where it works for me right now. At the start menu I normally just tap 'run as administrator'.

Comment: You are right, it still works with Win+R. But it also worked in the start menu (and still works on many computers)

Comment: Did not know that :) I suppose MS broke something with a recent patch?

Comment: See [this possible work-around](https://superuser.com/a/1244367/1535708).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it was a bug, which got fixxed with KB4023057 (Windows 11, I don't know the Windows 10 KB at the moment)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).